# what is setScrollbar() method practically doing inside modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was just going through the source of modal.js and came across the following method with which i have difficulty understanding,

```
  Modal.prototype.setScrollbar = function () {
    var bodyPad = parseInt((this.$body.css('padding-right') || 0), 10)
    if (this.bodyIsOverflowing) this.$body.css('padding-right', bodyPad +     this.scrollbarWidth)
  }
```

actually the above method is pretty straightforward ,

basically its storing the current padding on the body and then , 
checking if the body is overflowing and after that applying padding-right .

now my question is whats the practical or visual use of this function ??

i have gone through most functions in modal.js and they do make sense to me, except this function , some of the functions i have seen have pretty subtle effects , so its hard to pick , but with this function even i am unable to pick whats the subtle difference with or without it.

Can somebody elaborate. the function i am having difficulty with can be found on git. [Line 269](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L269).

Thank you.

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By increasing the size of the `right-padding` of the `body` by the width of the scroll bar it's ensuring that the scroll bar is not overlapping content...and that's why you probably don't notice it. It's really only something you'd notice if it wasn't being used (your content could potentially be overlapped by the scroll bar).

Comment: @Jake nice pussycat ! , Thanks , you just solved a big headache of mine , will try deleting the function and see the effect . TY again .